# Is it possible to describe any real number using algorithms with a finite length?

Tags: real-analysis

Starting from the integers we can encode any rational number using two integers. We can encode [many] irrational numbers using an algorithm that generates them with the desired accuracy.
For example, to generate the transcendental number $\pi$ we can use the Leibniz formula:

$\pi_n =\pi_{n-1} +   \frac{4 \times (-1)^n}{2n+1}$.

The recursion (or algorithm ) that describes the generation above has a rather short length.

Is it possible to generate all real numbers with a set of algorithms where there is an upper bound on the length of each algorithm?

Comment: There are only finitely many algorithms of a fixed length, hence only countably many of finite length.

Comment: Thanks. Now that you said it, it seems silly to ask.

Comment: Turing introduced the notion of [Computable Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) along the lines you propose.